# Копирование блока и изменение данных в нем

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
 function addNewGroup(button) {
   var html = $(button).parent().clone();
   console.log(html);
   $(button).parent().after(html);
   $(button).remove();
 }
```

```html
<div>
  <label>TEST GROUP</label>
  <div class="test_field">
    <label for="i-620">TEST field</label>
    <input id="i-620" type="text" placeholder="" name="test_field">
  </div>
  <div class="test_checkbox">
    <label for="i-621">dsadasdas</label>
    <input id="i-621" type="checkbox" name="adsasdsa" value="1">
  </div>
  <button type="button" onclick="addNewGroup($(this))">Вставить группу</button>
</div>
```

Есть следующий код, все просто, есть див, в нем элементы, нужно по нажатию кнопки копировать див и вставить следом. Это просто, но еще нужно изменить параметры name у инпутов, то есть если сначала было `name="test_field"` то в следующем диве `name="test_field1"` и тд, и так со всеми инпутами. Как это лучше сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
div = document.querySelector('.field');
var count = 0;

document.querySelector('button').onclick = function() {
  count++;
  div.innerHTML += div.firstElementChild.outerHTML;
  div.lastElementChild.placeholder = 'field' + count;
}
```

```html
<div class="field">
    <input type="text" placeholder="field" name="field">
</div>

<button>add field</button>
```

Comment: Если правильно понял, нужно что-то в этом роде? Для примера вместо name задал возрастание атрибуту placeholder

Answer (score 1):

[вот как вариант на JQuery](https://jsfiddle.net/ocjz3fkx/)

```
var count = 0;
$('#button').click(function(){
    count++;
    var clone = $('#container').clone().appendTo('#main_container');
    clone.find('[name*="one"]')
    .attr('name', 'one' + count)
    .attr('id', 'one' + count);;
});
```